# Set maximum column height in gridLayout to avoid overlapping

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

in my app I am encountering this problem:
[image]

As you can see i added the option to let the use specify a name through an edit text in an alertDialog. Hypotetically the user could enter an extremely long name, ruining the entire layout as the following rows will overlap. 
How can I enter a specified height and width for each row?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/gridview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:columnWidth="90dp"
          android:numColumns="auto_fit"
          android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:longClickable="true"
    />
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a single list item -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:padding="16dp">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="test text"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your layout xml files.

Comment: Sure I added those.

Answer (score 0):

Give some height to your row item parent or textview as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:padding="16dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="test text"
        />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Or setheight of your textview or give it maxlines

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:padding="16dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:minLines="6"
        tools:text="test text"
        />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, any chance I could ellipsise the text since it gets cut off straight?